# Change AccessDecisionManager to UnanimousBased in Grails Spring Security Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

We're using the Grails spring security plugin:

http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core

I simply want to change the default access decision manager from the default AffirmativeBased to UnanimousBased. I do not see it documented anywhere in the plugin manual:

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/

Does anyone know if it's possible to change this?

I added one additional voter, "myVoter" which is detected and working fine.

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.voterNames = [
    'myVoter', 'authenticatedVoter', 'roleVoter',
]
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? I have the same question.

Comment: I don't believe so. Spring security turned out to be a poor fit for our access control model. We wound up rolling our own.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Burt Beckwith's "Hacking the Grails Spring Security Plugin" [http://www.slideshare.net/gr8conf/hacking-the-grails-spring-security-plugins], it should be possible to simply provide a different implementation of the accessDecisionManager bean. Something like this:

accessDecisionManager(org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased)

in resources.groovy

When I tried this, I had trouble with the constructor syntax in the bean definition. The access decision manager wants a list of voters in the constructor and I couldn't quote figure out how to get my voters defined in config.groovy as parameters to the constructor. I was about to derive my own decision manager (with parameterless constructor) from UnanimousBased when I stumbled upon the source code for AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager in the Grails Spring Security Plugin. This class splits the voters in half... anything deriving from AuthenticatedVoter will immediately fail if any are denied (e.g. AUTHENTICATED_FULLY family), but all other voters will pass if any are granted (e.g. RoleVoter). I wanted the AuthenticatedVoter functionality for my custom voter so I simply derived from AuthenticatedVoter (making sure to override all of the interface methods so I didn't accidentally get any base class functionality) and stuck with the default decision manager.